# fetching data from database(mysql) and displaying it in the textbox in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

What is ajax.call()? It is a part of javascript or jquery?

Comment: k let me tell u.. $this->set('username',$username );..this is line under this i'm passing the value of username to controller(username). And i want to display this username in the textbox in View(updation.ctp)...                                     echo $this->form->input('username',array('value' =>'$username'));   As we all know that we can pass the value to a view using set function and display it in the view. But here when i show my output on the browser then it shows me'$username' instead of showing me the name of the user..Am i doing it wrong somewhere. Will u pls help.

Comment: i solved the problem.....mistake is i'm using'$username' ..just removed the single quotes..$username..thnks for ur support....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code into your view

```
echo $this->form->input('username',array('value' =>$username));
```